# Youtube API Java client library - How check if a video entry is available for mobile?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I have a content management server application written in Java. A background process goes through a list of video ids and fetches the details for those video ids using Youtube API.
I would like to check if a particular video entry is available for mobile or not.
I checked syndicate allowed like

```
String videoEntryUrl = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/"+videoID;
VideoEntry videoEntry = service.getEntry(new URL(videoEntryUrl), VideoEntry.class); 
if(!videoEntry.getXmlBlob().getBlob().contains("yt:accessControl permission='denied'  action='syndicate'")){
System.out.println("The video is syndicatable");
}
```

Checking for syndicate still not solved the problem and the server still lets in videos that cannot play on Android phone.
What is the right way to filter only the videos that can be played on mobile?

Comment: Does [this link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters) helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no single check to see whether a video is playable "on mobile".

There are a variety of different reasons why a particular video might not be playable on a particular platform, and unfortunately the only way to be absolutely sure whether a particular video will play in a particular player is to attempt to play it.

That being said, this blog post goes into more details about the types of common playback restrictions that crop up: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/12/understanding-playback-restrictions.html